# Определение имен и их сравнение

Tags: unix, shell, linux

Задача: если в корневую папку попадает файл с таким именем, как в папке "Archive", его нужно перенести в папку "Duplicate". Проблема: не знаю, как определить полное имя файла и как их сравнить, что бы выполнялась задача.

```
#/bin/sh

Path="C:/Dropbox/Study/test_telecom/"
ArchivePath="C:/Dropbox/Study/test_telecom/Archive/"
DuplicatePath="C:/Dropbox/Study/test_telecom/Duplicate/"

FileName="CLIENTS*.csv"
FileArchiveName="CLIENTS*.csv.gz"

ArchivePathWithFileArchiveName=$ArchivePath$FileArchiveName
PathWithFileName=$Path$FileName
PathWithFileArchiveName=$Path$FileArchiveName

echo $ArchivePath$FileArchiveName
echo $Path$FileName

echo 'File exist in folder Archive?'

if [ $ArchivePath$FileArchiveName=$Path$FileName ]

then 
    echo 'File CLIENTS*.csv already exist'
    mv $PathWithFileName $DuplicatePath 
    echo 'File move to Duplicate'
    exit 1
else 
    echo 'THIS IS NEW FILE'
    echo 'File CLIENTS archive in gzip'
    gzip -9 CLIENTS*.csv
    echo 'File CLIENTS go to Archive directory'
    mv $Path$FileArchiveName $ArchivePath
fi
exit 2
```

Comment: @yarosh_1990, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Как определить имя... не уверен, что правильно понимаю, но может как раз basename и делает это (`basename /hove/user/test.txt` возвращает `test.txt`).
Получив прежполагаемое имя, можно проверить его наличие таким способом `if [ -e $filename ]`. И самое главное - следите за пробелами в if:)

Answer (score 1):

для получения имени файла (без каталогов) можно использовать программу `basename`, а сравнивать не надо — достаточно проверить существование файла с нужным именем в нужном каталоге. пример:

```
$ tree
.
├── arch
│   └── file1
├── base
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
└── dups
$ for f in base/*; do b=$(basename $f); [ -e arch/$b ] && mv $f dups/$b; done
$ tree
.
├── arch
│   └── file1
├── base
│   └── file2
└── dups
    └── file1
```

Comment: назначил в метке [shell] язык lang-sh, теперь подсветка кода нормальная.

Comment: *назначил в метке [shell] язык lang-sh* — это как???

Comment: есть там список, доступный для модераторов. Можно указать синтаксис языка для каждой метки. У нас пока нигде не проставлен.

Comment: сравните: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nfXBV.png

Comment: уже [вижу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/info). да, крутая штука. наверно, надо бы побольше таких назначений сделать.

Comment: конечно надо, пока руки не дошли.